# Reversing elements of a list using recursion

Tags: java, list, recursion

The aim is to write a code which reverses the elements of a list with help of recursion.

```
public static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return new LinkedList<Integer>();
    } else {
        List<Integer> output = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        output.add(((LinkedList<Integer>) input).removeLast());
        reverse(input);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting only the first element right, the rest of the list just does not show up. What am I missing?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the returned `List<Integer>` from your `reverse(input)` recursive call.  You should be returning it, assigning it to a variable, or doing something similar with it.  Instead, it's being discarded.

Comment: Robert is right. You probably need a second parameter. One for the input to gradually remove from, one for a new list to append to.

Comment: I thought I have two parameters – input and output.

  `output.add(((LinkedList<Integer>) input).removeLast());`

I thought I am adding the last elements of the input to the front of the output with this part of the code, hence reversing it.

Comment: I agree with above comments but I also think you're doing the recursive part wrong. Your last call should be to the recursive function again. Not returning the output. At least if you are going for recursion.

Comment: Thank you all for help, it is working now but I still need some time to properly understand it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like in below code. Note that I'm using `removeFirst()` method.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Reverse {

  public static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
      return new LinkedList<Integer>();
    } else {
      Integer first = ((LinkedList<Integer>) input).removeFirst();
      List<Integer> output = reverse(input);
      output.add(first);
      return output;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> input = new LinkedList<>();
    input.add(15);
    input.add(37);
    input.add(26);
    input.add(18);
    input.add(31);

    System.out.println("Input  : " + input);
    System.out.println("Output : " + reverse(input));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How it was mentioned in comments, you need a second parameter and probably don't need return value:

```
public static void reverse(List<Integer> input, List<Integer> output) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    output.add(((LinkedList<Integer>) input).removeLast());
    reverse(input, output);
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Integer> input = new LinkedList<>();
// fill it with values
List<Integer> output = new LinkedList<>();

reverse(input, output);
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using for convinience a Stack for its pop method.

```
public static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> input) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack();
    stack.addAll(input);
    return reverse(stack,new LinkedList<>());
  }

  public static List<Integer> reverse(Stack<Integer> input,LinkedList<Integer> output) {
     if (input.isEmpty()) {
       return output;
     }
     output.addFirst(input.pop());
     reverse(input, output);
    return output;
  }
```

If you want to skip the re-addition of the elements you need to maintain an index, or use a LinkedList which is aware of the first and the last elements.
Here it is with maintaining index and a pure List api:

```
public static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> input) {


     return reverse(input,new LinkedList<>(),0);
  }

  public static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> input,LinkedList<Integer> output,int index) {
     if (index == input.size()) {
       return output;
     }
     output.addFirst(input.get(index));
     reverse(input, output,++index);
    return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will work for you

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Integer> input = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            List<Integer> output = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            input.add(5);
            input.add(1);
            input.add(3);
            int size = input.size();
            System.out.println(reverse(input, size, output));

        }

        public static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> input, int sizeOfInput, List<Integer> output) {

            if (sizeOfInput > 0) {
                output.add(((LinkedList<Integer>) input).removeLast());
                sizeOfInput--;
                reverse(input, sizeOfInput, output);
            }
            return output;
        }
```

Comment: The missing part was in else statement : 
        List<Integer> output = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // Every time you were creating new LinkedList object